# How to make the comment to be in specific topic?

Tags: php, html

I need help. I have problem when commenting on topic. I want when the user comment in specific topic, it will appear only in the specific topic. The problem is when user comment in the specific topic, the comment can be seen in any topic available including the specific topic. Previously i store in comment.txt file but now i already delete the comment.txt file and make a database to store the comment based on what reply has told me. The problem is still the same. How to make it appear in topic A rather than appear on other topic. Hope anyone can help me because i has been trying to solve this for 4 days. Below is the updated code:

```
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ourmusic");

    $post_title = $_GET["post_title"];
    //echo "<h1>".$post_title."</h1>";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT poster, post_title, post_desc FROM posting WHERE post_title = '$post_title';");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


    echo "</br><h1>".$data["post_title"]."</h1>";
    echo "<sup>by <b>".$data["poster"]."</b></sup <br><br><br><br><hr><br><br>"; 
    echo "<p>".$data["post_desc"]."</p><br><br><br>";
    ?>

    <!-- Back to Forum -->
    <a href="forum.php">
        <button type="submit" name="back-btn" class="btn btn-success">Back</button> 
    </a>

    <a href="comment.php">
        <button type="submit" name="back-btn" class="btn btn-success">Comment</button>
    </a><br><br>

    <p>Comments:</p>

    <!-- Post And Show The Comment -->
     <?php
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","ourmusic");
        
        $query_c = "SELECT * FROM [ourmusic].[posting].[dbo].[post_title]";

        $result_c = mysqli_query($connection, $query_c);
        ?>
          <?php

          $username = $_SESSION['username'];

          while($data_c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_c))
            {
              $poster= $data_c['poster'];
              $comment_content = $data_c['comment_content'];
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><b><?php echo $poster; ?></b></td><br>
                <td><?php echo $comment_content;?></td><br>
              </tr>
              <?php
            }
        ?>
```

And this is for my Final Year Project.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're saving comments in text files?

Comment: easy to say, i'm doing research for comment system, but most of the research that i found, save comments in text files. They show how to create comment system and save it in text files.

Comment: What's your exact problem? Why not store the comments in the database? This will make it much easier to show only the comments for a specific topic

Answer (score 0):

Rather than save comments in a text file and read them later on, it will be ideal to save the comments in a database.

Your table could contain columns for comments and topics.

For example, for **Topic A**, save the topic as well as the comment in the table at the point of commenting.

When fetching the comments, query the database for the comments, filtering them by topics.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll will do it.